# QTableView format individual row and columns

Tags: qt

Maybe what I'm about to ask is so basic that i missed it somewhere, but i google all kind of things and i have not been able to find the answer. I have the following table view, feed from a SQLite table:

```
  body = new QSqlTableModel(parent,data->m_db);
  body->setTable("C"+QString::number(markTime.toSecsSinceEpoch()));
  body->select();
  ui->bodyView->setModel(body);
  ui->bodyView->sortByColumn(0,Qt::AscendingOrder);
  ui->bodyView->setColumnWidth(0,30);
  ui->bodyView->setColumnWidth(1,80);
  for(int x=2;x<ui->columns->maximum()+2;x++) ui->bodyView->setColumnWidth(x,40);
  ui->bodyView->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
  ui->bodyView->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
  ui->bodyView->setAlternatingRowColors(true);
  ui->bodyView->show();
```

Further down in the program i add data to the table to be displayed. That works with no problems. My question is:
How i can access individual lines to format the row, i would like to change the size of the font, format the display to show number aligned and make it boldface but only for a specific row.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean by line?, you could explain me please, you could show an image of what you want.

Comment: When you say line, do you mean a column, or a row, or is there a certain cell?

Comment: Sorry, i meant row, i just updated the post. What i want is for example make row 6 with a bigger font, boldface and change the background, to drive the eyes of the user to that row. The same could be true for a column, or a cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt's proposed solution to customize the details of individual view items rendering (and editing) is via [delegates](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#delegate-classes). The level of customization depends on your use-case: you can do some minor adjustment like changing a font or you can draw something completely special, like what's shown in  [Star Delegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-stardelegate-example.html) example.

There are basically two options to proceed with a custom delegate: either you subclass [QStyledItemDelegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#subclassing-qstyleditemdelegate) (or its base class [QItemDelegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemdelegate.html) if you need to draw the items of Qt's datatypes somewhat specially) and change some particular details of interest to you leaving the rest to the base class or you subclass [QAbstractItemDelegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemdelegate.html) to have full control over the view item's appearance and behavior.

A delegate can be set up for the view in either of three different ways:

1. for the whole view (i.e. for all model items) via [setItemDelegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegate) method
2. for a particular column via [setItemDelegateForColumn](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegateForColumn) method
3. for a particular row via [setItemDelegateForRow](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegateForRow) method

For the sake of example, here's how you can specify a slightly larger font size for the item rendering:

```
class CustomDelegate: public QStyledItemDelegate
{
public:
    virtual void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                         const QModelIndex &index) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
};

void CustomDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                         const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (!index.isValid()) {
        return;
    }

    QFont font = option.font;
    font.setPointSize(font.pointSize() + 1);

    QStyleOptionViewItem localOption(option);
    localOption.font = font;
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, localOption, index);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, i think i got the idea. I will try and see.

Comment: Tested it, this is exactly want I needed. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. If you find the answer useful, please mark it as the accepted one, thanks.